# JSQuery: How to add and retrieve column attributes?

Tags: html, jquery, django

I'm reading a table from my database using JQuery and I want to create a data type attribute by column in order to perform certain operations by column. So far, I have the following:

```js
var table = $('#maintable').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "type": "GET",
    "url": "/cvs/PDFeditor/request/",
    "data": function(d) {
      d.placeholder = "asdf";
    }
  },
  "columns": [{
      "className": 'edit-control',
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "width": "12px",
      "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
    }, {
      "className": 'delete-control',
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "width": "12px",
      "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button>'
    }, {
      "data": "investor",
      "class": 'inv-editable',
      "data-type": 'investor'
    }, {
      "data": "amount",
      "type": "num-fmt",
      "class": 'inv-editable',
      "data-type": 'amount'
    }, {
      "data": "code",
      "class": 'inv-editable',
      "data-type": 'code'
    }
  ],
  "pageLength": 15,
  "order": [ [5, "desc"] ]
});
```

My purpose is to store the "data-type" attribute into a variable to update the column in the database prior:

```js
$('#maintable tbody').on('dblclick', '.inv-editable', function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  var data_type = $(this).data("type")

  if (data_type == 'investor') {
    var input = "<input type = 'text' class = 'input-data' value ='" + value + "' class='form-control' type="investor">";
  } else if (data_type == 'amount') {
    var input = "<input type = 'text' class = 'input-data' value ='" + value + "' class='form-control' type="amount">";
  }
  
  $(this).html(input);
  $(this).removeClass("inv-editable")
});
```

How can I retrieve the data-type attribute from the table definition?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `dblclick` event handler has invalid syntax in it. You mixed up the quotes.

Comment: `var` has function scope. `var input = ...` in each branch of the `if ... else if ...` is not necessary (and will be changed automatically because of hoisting)